# Can't get public class GUI extends Frame implements ActionListener working

Tags: java, oop, user-interface, actionlistener, abstract

[Screenshot of a snippet from my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Cp2M.png)

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage; 
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO; 
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
 private TextField buy = new TextField(30);
 private Button appl;

 public GUI(){
    super("GUI");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setSize(400,150);
    setTitle("Stock Market Exchange");
    setVisible(true);

    aapl = new Button("Buy AAPL share");
    add(aapl);
    aapl.setEnabled(true);
    aapl.setBounds(35,6,112,36);
    aapl.setBackground(new Color(214,217,223));
    aapl.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
    aapl.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            createAAPLshare();
        }
    });
    add(buy);
    aapl.setVisible(true);
}
```

"public class GUI extends Frame implements ActionListener" - keeps returning an error because GUI isn't abstract and can't override actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in java.awt.event.ActionListener.
But I just can't seem to figure out exactly where and why this error keeps returning. I've tried to search up various methods to fix it but there's still a compiler error. What am I missing?

Comment: don't post a (link to) a screenshot of code, post your actual code here

Comment: it doesn't say you CAN'T override actionPerformed, the error says that you don't override actionPerformed, while you should, since you implement the ActionListener interface

Answer (score 0):

It just means you need to provide an implementation for actionPerformed(). ActionListener is an interface so if you implement it in a class you are expected to have whatever methods are in the interface filled out in your class somewhere. This page should give you more info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Answer (score 0):

You're missing exactly what the error tells you: a concrete implementation of the `actionPerformed()` method (since you implement ActionListener interface)

Either provide an implementation of this method in your GUI class (and use it accordingly in one or more components of your GUI class), or remove the `implements ActionListener` part from your class if you don't need it

For the former, add the implementation of the method in your class :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            createAAPLshare();
}
```

And then in the relevant part :

```
aapl.addActionListener(this);
```

For the latter, just leave your code as it is, but remove the `implements ActionListener` from you class signature

Either way should work, you choose

Comment: I just edited my original post to include more of my code, where I believe I have already implemented actionPerformed(), do you think I'm just not accurately addressing the right issue?

Comment: @x.alvina.x no, you are just creating a new anonymous implementation of ActionListener. if you want to work like that, remove the implements ActionListener from your class signature and try again